# How to increase content assist tooltip size in Eclipse / PDT

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, eclipse-pdt

I'm using PDT with Eclipse and the Content Assist tooltips (e.g. for class method descriptions) are too small to be useful.  Usually, only the first few words are visible.  Is there a preference to increase the sizes of these?  I have plenty of screen real estate, so I want to make them much larger.

Thanks

Edit: Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology -- I'm talking about the PHPDoc-style tooltips.  Here's a screenshot:

Edit 2: Screenshot no longer available.

Comment: Thanks; just updated to note that image is no longer available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to simply grab the pop-up at the lower right corner and drag it larger. It will keep that size the next time it opens (at least it does for me in Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6).

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is with the description tooltips as in the screenshot I added above.  I can resize the content-assist popup that has the list of class methods or PHP functions, but the tooltip above disappears when the mouse is moved.

Comment: Ah sorry I confused PDT and PDE again and thought you were talking about Java development. These hover pop-ups can be enlarged if you hover over them for a moment (or press F2), then the corner to resize will appear (at least it does in the Java environment). Unfortunately, these don't remember the size for me.

Comment: The F2 is just what I need.  Thanks!